How do I count matched values that occured in specific date ranges for two datasets?
I have to pull two datasets from an API, shape and compare the data, then output to a CSV file. I have the data in two polars dataFrames using Python. The first, I'll call "events", has a list of datetime ranges and a list of values, "event_values", as shown below.
"events" dataset example:
events = pl.DataFrame({
          "startdatetime": ["2021-01-01 00:00:00"], ["2021-01-01 00:10:00"], ["2021-01-01 00:20:00"],
            "enddatetime": ["2021-01-01 00:15:00"], ["2021-01-01 00:25:00"], ["2021-01-01 00:35:00"],            
           "event_values": ["1", "2", "3"]        , ["2", "3", "4"]        , ["4", "5", "6"]       })

The second dataset, I'll call "test_data", has a datetime and values, "test_values", as shown below.
"test_data" dataset example:
test_data = pl.DataFrame({
                          "datetime": ["2021-01-01 00:02:00"] 
                                    , ["2021-01-01 00:07:00"]
                                    , ["2021-01-01 00:13:00"]
                                    , ["2021-01-01 00:15:00"]
                                    , ["2021-01-01 00:16:00"]
                                    , ["2021-01-01 00:19:00"]
                                    , ["2021-01-01 00:22:00"]
                                    , ["2021-01-01 00:25:00"]
                                    , ["2021-01-01 00:28:00"]
                                    , ["2021-01-01 00:37:00"]
                     , "test_values": [1], [3], [2], [7], [3], [4], [5], [6], [4], [5]}) 


I have to count all "test_values" in "test_data" that occurred during any datetime range in "events" and matches one of the "event_values" for that datetime range. I have to add the count of all matches to a new column, "numEvents", and output the complete events dataFrame with the newly added column to CSV. With the example data I've shown the output would be as below.
Example output:
events = pl.DataFrame({
          "startdatetime": ["2021-01-01 00:00:00"], ["2021-01-01 00:10:00"], ["2021-01-01 00:20:00"],
            "enddatetime": ["2021-01-01 00:15:00"], ["2021-01-01 00:25:00"], ["2021-01-01 00:35:00"],            
           "event_values": ["1", "2", "3"]        , ["2", "3", "4"]        , ["4", "5", "6"],
              "numEvents": [3]                    , [4]                    , [3]                   }) 
                         # rows 1, 2, 3             rows 3, 5, 6, 7          rows 7, 8, 9


I've been attempting to do this for a few days now and no matter what method I attempt, I have not been able to get anywhere with this. I would normally keep going at it until I figured it out, but I'm on a time limit with the deadline fast approaching. What would be the best way to do this?
My last attempt I tried making a new dataFrame called "matched_data" filled with the "events_data" timeranges and an added column named "match_index". Since I had no luck with any other method, I was trying to interate through the test_rows and event_rows and add the row indexes for all matches. I would then use the indexes to compare the data from those rows explicitly. It's very inefficient, but I've been out of luck. I tried using polars built in iterators to try this with no luck, so for a last attempt I tried below:
for test_row in test_data.iter_rows(named=True):
    for event_row in events.iter_rows(named=True):
        if (test_row['datetime'] >= event_row['startdatetime']) & (test_row['datetime'] <= event_row['enddatetime']):
            matched_data[event_row['index'],'match_index'] =  (event_row['index'])

This didn't work either. I thought using datetime.is_between() would be best, but couldn't get it working.

Why is row 5 missing from the first numEvents? It contains a 3? Same for row 2 in the second, as row 2 contains a 3, should it not be counted? Shouldn't  numEvents be [4], [5], [5] instead of [3], [4], [3]?

They are not counted because they occurred outside the datetime range for their respective columns. For example, row 5 does contain a 3, but it occurred at 00:16:00 and the range for the first column is 00:00:00 to 00:15:00 (startdatetime to enddatetime).

Ah, you're right - I'll leave my comment, in case someone else misses it as well, unless you want to update the question with a clarification.

You might be interested in the answers (and links therein) that I got in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78912175/combine-cross-between-2-dataframe-efficiently

how are rows 3, 5, 6, 7 fall into second row' filter? row 7 has value 5 which is not within [2,3,4]?

@RomanPekar Sorry I took so long to reply, been very busy. You are right, I was up for 32+ hours working on this stuff and I guess when I wrote this I messed up the numbers due to fatigue.

update join_where() was added in version 1.7.0, but it it looks like it doesn't support all checks so you still need a filter():
(
    events
    .join_where(
        test_data,
        pl.col.datetime >= pl.col.startdatetime,
        pl.col.datetime <= pl.col.enddatetime
    )
    .filter(pl.col.event_values.list.contains(pl.col.test_values))
    .group_by("startdatetime", "enddatetime", "event_values")
    .agg(pl.col.test_values.count())
)

previous You can use cross join() and filter():
(
    events
    .join(test_data, how="cross")
    .filter(
        pl.col.datetime.is_between(pl.col.startdatetime, pl.col.enddatetime),
        pl.col.event_values.list.contains(pl.col.test_values),
    )
    .group_by("startdatetime", "enddatetime", "event_values")
    .agg(pl.col.test_values.count())
)

Or use DuckDB integration with Polars:
import duckdb

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        e.*,
        (
            select count(*)
            from test_data as t
            where
                t.datetime between e.startdatetime and e.enddatetime and
                list_contains(e.event_values, t.test_values)
        ) as numEvents
    from events as e
""").pl()


This didn't work without some changes, mostly the Polars example. When I can I'll edit and post the final version I used. I did have an issue I haven't figured out, the only fix I can think of is messy. The issue is that when the test data matches multiple events, only the first match gets counted. The fix I can think of would be to split all events that have matching values into separate dataframes and test them against the test data individually. This is difficult though because there's hundreds of samples, events can last a day or more, and the test data can occur in seconds.
